# C++: Derived classes, "no matching constructor" error

Tags: c++, class, derived-class

I've been working on this assignment for a while. Here's the instructions:

> You are to design an abstract class called Employee whose members are
>   as given below (make them protected):
>
> Data members: char *name, long int ID
>
> Two constructors: A Default constructor // intitialize data memebrs to
>   the default values and a copy constructor
>
> Methods: setPerson (char *n, long int id) //allows user to set
>   information for each person A function called Print () // should be a
>   virtual function, that prints the data attributes of the class. and a
>   destructor
>
> Also define two classes that derived from class Employee, called
>   Manager and Secretary. Each class should inherit all members from the
>   base class and has its own data members and member functions as well.
>   The Manager should have a data member called degree for his/her
>   undergraduate degree (e.g. diploma, bachelor, master, doctor), the
>   Secretary should have her contract (can be a Boolean value 1/0 for
>   permanent/temporary).
>
> All member functions of derived class should be overrided from their
>   base class.
>
> Write the following main() to test your classes
>
> ```
> int main() {
> Employee * p = new Manager(“Bruce Lee”, 0234567, “Dr.”);
> P.print();
> Secretary p2;
> p2.setPerson(“Wilma Jones”, 0341256, “permanent”);
> delete p;
> p = & p2;
> p.Print();
> return 0;
> }
> ```

This is everything I've come up with so far, but I'm pretty sure it's riddled with mistakes and that my arguments and variable types are all off.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Employee{
protected:
    char *name;
    long int ID;
public:
    Employee();
    Employee(Employee&);
    void setPerson(char * n, long int eID) {
        name = n;
        ID = eID; };
    virtual void Print(){
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "ID: " << ID << endl; };
};

class Manager: public Employee {
protected:
    char *degree;
public:
    void setPerson(char * n, long int eID, char * d){
        name = n;
        ID = eID;
        degree = d;
    };
    void Print() {
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "ID: " << ID << endl;
        cout << "Degree: " << degree << endl;
    };
};

class Secretary: public Employee {
protected:
    bool contract;
public:
    void setPerson(char * n, long int eID, string c){
        name = n;
        ID = eID;
        if (c == "permanent") contract = true;
        else contract = false;
    };
    void Print(){
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "ID: " << ID << endl;
        cout << "Contract: " << contract << endl;
    };
};

int main() {
    Employee * P = new Manager("Bruce Lee", 0234567, "Dr.");
    P.Print();
    Secretary P2;
    P2.setPerson("Wilma Jones", 0341256, "permanent");
    delete P;
    P = & P2;
    P.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error on line 62 (the first line of the main code):

> No matching constructor for initialization of Manager

I've tried reading similar questions, but they haven't helped me much. I think the most confusing thing is contract being a bool value and the use of char arguments. Any guidance at all is appreciated.

Comment: Errors on lines 57 and 62 where it says `P.Print();` do not give the error you mentioned. More likely they give the `left of '.Print' must have class/struct/union` error message.

Comment: @RawN my line 62 is different from the line 62 here (since Xcode adds the comments at the beginning.) That's why I specified that it's the first line of the main code, but you are correct in that the print functions aren't working either. I didn't mention it because I recognize it as an error from Manager not initializing.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is pretty straight-forward: you don't have any constructor for `Manager` (or `Employee`) that takes a string, integer (?), and string as arguments.

Comment: I'm supposed to use char * and int for the arguments though. That's what's confusing me. Also, I changed all the chars to strings, and it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: @hopillium Did you add a "Manager(...)" constructor to Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the constructor employee but not defined it.
Look at the class employee, Under publc you have declared

```
Employee();
Employee(Employee&);
```

But you have not defined the function. You need

```
Employee :: Employee()
{
    bla bla bla
}
```

and another one for the other signature.